# Im looping to display the rows in the database but other rows are not included inside the html table

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST["Search"]))
{
$resz=mysqli_query($link,"select*from tblschedule where Destination = 
'$_POST[Destination]' and Origin = '$_POST[Origin]' and Date = 
'$_POST[Date]'");
```

Code for search

```
$count=mysqli_num_rows($resz);

if($count>=1){
```

if there's a row to search then display

```
echo "</br></br>
<div class=container>
    <div class=table-responsive>
        <table class = table>

            <tr>
                <th class=col-xs-2> TripCode    </th> 
                <th class=col-xs-2> Origin      </th>
                <th class=col-xs-2> Destination </th>
                <th class=col-xs-2> Date        </th>
                <th class=col-xs-2> Time        </th>
                <th class=col-xs-2> Action      </th>
            </tr>";

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resz))
            {?>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $row['TripCode']; ?>        </td>
                <td> <?php echo $row['Origin']; ?>          </td>
                <td> <?php echo $row['Destination']; ?>     </td>
                <td> <?php echo $row['Date']; ?>            </td>
                <td> <?php echo $row['Time']; ?>            </td>
                <td> <?php echo "<a href=webbook.php?
                id=".$row['TripCode'].">Book</a><br />"; ?></td>    
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }} else{ echo "<center>No results were found.</center>"; }}
 ?>
```

Code is successfully getting the rows I want but only one row has a table and the others don't have. I want each row to have a table of their own.

Comment: why would each row have its own table? Aren't they from the same table in the database?

Comment: I mean the <table> </table> other rows are not inside the html table element

Comment: u need loop the whole <table></table> to have the result. One row have his own table. u only loop through <tr><td></td></tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like your `<table>` and the two `<div>` tag is within the while loop. remove it and put outside of the loop.